# Why HashMap use length minus 1 to calculate index?

Tags: java, hashmap

I am analysis the source code of **`HashMap`** in **jdk7**,and I found that when we invoke `put()`method to add elements,it will use `indexFor()`to calculate the index and store the element in the array,the method is listed as below.

Now I am wondering why it use **`h & (length-1)`** to get the index? Is it used for to get more random array index? Can we use **`length`** or **`length-2`**(if exists) instead?

Can anyone help me to understand this? Thanks in advance!

```
static int indexFor(int h, int length) {
    // assert Integer.bitCount(length) == 1 : "length must be a non-zero power of 2";
    return h & (length-1);
}
```

Comment: `length` is always a power of 2, so `length-1` is always a bitmask that provides the same thing as `% length`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it used for to get more random array index?

No

> Can we use length or length-2(if exists) instead?

No

This is just a mathematical trick. To map your hash to the range `[0, L)` you calculate `hash % L`. Division can be expensive, so the developers choose to take advantage of how numbers are stored in binary. This works only for powers of two because only a single bit is set, subtracting one sets all less-significant bits and unsets the original bit. Binary-AND-ing this to our hash has the same result as calculating the modulo, every bit which is more-significant than we can handle is just dropped.